# A question from my real analysis qualifying exam

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be in $L_1(\Bbb R^N)$ and $g$ be in $L_q(\Bbb R^N)$ for $q \in (1, \infty)$. Show that $(f*g)(x)= \int_{\Bbb R^N}f(x-y)g(y)dy$ is in $L_q(\Bbb R^N)$ and that $||(f*g)(x) ||_q \le ||f||_1||g||_q$

I had trouble getting past the following part.

$||(f*g)(x) ||_q^q= \int_{\Bbb R^N} \big  |\int_{\Bbb R^N}f(x-y)g(y)dy \big|^q dx  \le \int_{\Bbb R^N} \left(\int_{\Bbb R^N}|f(x-y)||g(y)|dy \right)^q dx $

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You need the integral form of Minkowski's inequality.  (Riesz-Thorin interpolation is another option.)